# How do I serialize my class to send it as urlencoded with refit

Tags: c#, json, serialization, xamarin.forms, refit

Hi there I'm trying to send a POST method with refit, using postman so far I can say it's working, if I send the data with the x-www-form-encoded option, the json I send looks like this

```
{
  "apt": "APT",
  "apartment": "A103",
  "author": "Someone",
  "is_public": "True",
  "is_complaint": "True",
  "show_name": "True",
  "title": "fhj",
  "details": "vvkko"
}
```

I constructed my class in visual studio and my model to match it pasting that to json

```
namespace App.Models
{
    public class ManyComplaints
    {
        public SingleComplaint data { get; set; }
    }
    public class SingleComplaint
    {
        public string apt { get; set; }
        public string apartment { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
        public string is_public { get; set; }
        public string is_complaint { get; set; }
        public string show_name { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string details { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Here I'm not sure if I did right it's my api caller

```
 [Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
 [Post("/api/complaints/")]
 Task SubmitComplaint([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)]SingleComplaint complaint);
```

And in this is the code that's sending the data

```
public async Task Post()
{
    SingleComplaint data = new SingleComplaint 
    {
        is_public = ShowPost,
        is_complaint = Complaint,
        show_name = ShowName,
        author = Preferences.Get("UserName", null),
        apt0 = Preferences.Get("Apt", null),
        apartment = Preferences.Get("Apartment", null),
        title = TitleEntry.Text,
        details = DetailsEntry.Text
    };

    try
    {                
        var myApi = RestService.For<IApiService>(Constants.webserver);
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        ManyComplaints complaint = await myApi.SubmitComplaint(data);
        await DisplayAlert("Thanks", "Your message has been succesfully delivered", "Ok");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
    }
}
```

Tried to use the line as `string complaint = await myApi.SubmitComplaint(serialized);` and also change that as string instead of the `ManyComplaints` class,
also tried to change the model as just the singlecomplaints but I couldn't get it to work, what I'm I missing or how do I make it work?

Comment: @ Herb - are you getting any exception ? Also expected response change to var response = await myApi.SubmitComplaint(data); ...this is because your api method is not defined to return any strongly type response object.... if you want ManyComplaints as response object then update your method as Task<ManyComplaints> .... One more thing verify your Api address... may address will be like [Post("/api/complaints")]

Comment: it's returning a null value in my complaint variable and I'm getting server 500 in the app, I dont quite get this from refit it's the first time I use it and not much examples around, adrees is correct :(

Answer (score 11):

This answer might have come very late. But recently I was working on a similar use case. And the below code worked for me.

**API Declaration (using Refit)**

```
[Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
[Get("")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetData([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] FormUrlEncodedContent content);
```

**Calling the API**

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> contentKey = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("apt", "APT"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("apartment", "A103"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("author", "Someone")
};

FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(contentKey);

HttpResponseMessage response = someClass.GetData(content);
```